# Manage multiple fetch requests in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS server that has GET method route.
It would be necessary to get a large JSON file at once.
This gives an error when the `result.foo` has over 20 elements. But, I have over 500. 
Should I use multithread somehow or what would be the best options?
It is not possible to do GET request multiple times and thereby reduce the number of requests.

Below is my working example. If I map only 20 elements, it works. But, I need all 500.

```js
app.get("/search", (req, res, next) => {
  fetch(URL)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      let arr = [];

      //This result has over 500 elements always
      result.foo.map((r, index) => {
        let newURL = `foo.com/${r.id}`;
        arr.push(newURL);
      });

      Promise.all(
        arr.map((url) =>
          fetch(url).then((response) => {
            //This reponse has over 100 elements always
            return response.json();
          })
        )
      )
        .then((value) => {
          let sorted = value.filter((res) => !!res.foo.length);
          return res.json(sorted);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not certain what the problem is, but I've created a [CodeSandbox on how to fetch multiple requests in your Express route handler](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-fetch-requests-node-vz29o). I tried to mimic your code as closely as possible using `async/await`. I also created a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinydhan/a08e70c6b6c738eb2bbc216f31dfaa27) that contains refactored code for your route handler.

Comment: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinydhan/a08e70c6b6c738eb2bbc216f31dfaa27) is an exact example of what this code should do. 
Certain problem is that `initialRequest` size is > 500, and `subsequentRequests` each fetch has over 80 element inside. Now when I start, it runs error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, but I know these fetch URL-s are correct (checked them, each returns correct JSON). 
Can it be server side issue, or `Promise.all` not handle it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Now I got `Too Many Requests` error from API and that is not problem that I can solve. It is API provider server poblem, Thanks @khan for code.

Comment: Great! Glad it works!